# TimePicker dialog with toast when the time setted is reach?

Tags: android, dialog, android-preferences, android-timepicker

I want to create a simple timepicker dialog in my preferences screen? My question is: Is it possible? Or the timepicker must be in the MainActivity? Can someone explain me how set an alarm in this timepicker dialog and show a Toast when the time setted is reach?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the android guide for 
[Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)?
I believe it pretty much explains what you want to do.

You can visit this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/) as well.